# Variable 'number1' might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I am getting this error `Error:(100,22) java:variable number1 might not have been initialized` and the same happens for `number2`. This is when I try to use the variable in an `if` statement.

Where as, it says `Variable 'number1' is never assigned` and again the same for `number2` when I declared them.

Setting the value to 0 will not help as in the last else if statement the statement will always be true.

```
public class event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a) {
        double number1, number2, add, substract, multiply, divide;
        String operator = a.getActionCommand();

        if (operator.equals("+")) {
            add = number1 + number2;
            result.setText(number1 + "+" + number2 + "=" + add);
            result.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
        else if (operator.equals("-")) {
            substract = number1 - number2;
            result.setText(number1 + "-" + number2 + "=" + substract);
            result.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
        else if (operator.equals("*")) {
            multiply = number1 * number2;
            result.setText(number1 + "*" + number2 + "=" + multiply);
            result.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }
        else if (operator.equals("/")) {
            if (number2 == 0) {
                result.setText("Cannot divide by zero");
                result.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }
            else {
                divide = number1 / number2;
                result.setText(number1 + "/" + number2 + "=" + divide);
                result.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not clear in the message "*Variable 'number1' might not have been initialized*"?

Comment: You didn't initialize variable number1

Answer (score 2):

Local variables must be initialized.

You need to initialized your below local `double` variables.

```
double number1, number2, add, substract, multiply, divide;
```

Comment: I'm editing your answer because question is tagged Java, no need to write "In Java".

Answer (score 2):

```
add = number1 + number2;
```

up until this line (and all following) you did not instantiate, nor assign a value to, `number1` and `number2`. So, how is the JVM to know what you want to do?

Comment: Any idea what value I should assign them as?

Comment: the value you want them to start with. Normally, this would be 0, but since you want them to add up to something, they might be values read from a JTextField.

Comment: This code is a calculator program and the number1 and number2 should be values read from JTextField. However I have no idea how to initialize the double variable. If I do 0 than the calculator will always output 0

Comment: double result = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText()) + Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());

you don't even need those number1 and number2 variables.

Comment: Damn, I am still having trouble with that, because the rest of the code goes red. Is there anyway I could message you the whole code and you could edit it for me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: What a replied was not a "copy-paste" code, rather an example. you need to replace it by the names of your JTextFields, and make sure it's in the class of the JTextFields.
What part is causing you trouble? Getting the values, or converting to a double?

Comment: I don't know what to do with the if statement, and the number1/number2 variables left in it

Comment: You are using the if statement to see what action to take, so you need that. But, if you change the code the way I showed you in a previous reply, you don't need that number1 and number2 variables. The information they would/should hold, are, as you stated, in the JTextFields.

Comment: When I do the double result thing you said it says that result is never used